# Typo error in FAQ

Tags: support, status-completed

At the time of this writing, the FAQ on the main site starts with the following sentence:

> Japanese Language and Usage - Stack Exchange is for tudents, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language.

I think "tudents" is a typo there. Would an admin/moderator please fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, just a typo. It has been fixed.